# Как мне разрешить пользователю просмотр только его объектов на сайте?

Tags: django

Например на одной странице пользователь добавил объект через форму в модель, а потом перешёл на следующую страницу и должен увидеть только этот объект. На данный момент он видит объекты всех пользователей.
Потом ещё мне нужно будет знать, какой пользователь, какие объекты добавил.

Можете подсказать хотя бы куда копать, где искать инфу...

Я думаю, что можно в моделе пользователей прописывать стандартные права относительно одной модели базы данных. Но не знаю, как это попробовать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто добавьте вашей модели поле, указывающее на юзера, добавившего объекта:

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Photo(models.Model):
    account = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='photos', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

При создании объекта не забудьте сохранить пользователя.

И в функции, генерирующей страницу, когда достаёте все объекты, добавьте фильтр по текущему юзеру, чтобы оставить только его объекты:

```py
from django.views import View
from django.shortcuts import render

class PhotosView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        objects = Photo.objects.filter(account=request.user).order_by('name')
        render(request, 'photos.html', {'user_photos': objects})
```